# How to close xml dialog outside of the dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Is it  any way to close xml dialog outside of the dialg?

here is my code :

```
Dialog dialog;  
        public void my_dialog() {
                final Context context = this;
                //final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); // Intern
            dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_xml_dialog);  
        final TextView txt_close = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_txt_close);

        txt_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();  // works    
                    }
                });
            dialog.show();
            }
```

But if I try to close the dialog outside of dialog, it does not work

```
        dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: dialog.dismiss();  where u call this method?

Comment: I try to call and to close the dialog from Volley and timer. I can display the dialog, but i can not close it. I just want to close the old one before displaying new Dialog. I get many Dialogs.

Comment: you should make sure you call dialog.dismiss from UI thread

Comment: Try dialog.cancel() or check that dismiss()  is called on the main thread

Comment: I have moved `dialog = new Dialog(context);`  to **OnCreate**, then it works fine now.